# Use AngularJS Services in javascript library (bootstrap-year-calendar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to use bootstrap-year-calendar in an AngularJS application.
https://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/
Basically the goal is for an employee to create their vacations and see them in the calendar.
I have services that will insert and get their holidays in a mongodb database, but i need to set the dataSource variable in the javascript library at the start with the values returned from the service and get the values from the selectRange event to call a post service. I'm calling all my services in the controllers but in this case i need to call them in this javascript library.
I'll just post the parts of the code where i need to call the services

```
(function($) {
    var Calendar = function(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        this.element.addClass('calendar');

        this._initializeEvents(options);
        this._initializeOptions(options);
        this._render();
    };

    Calendar.prototype = {
        constructor: Calendar,
        _initializeOptions: function(opt) {
            if(opt == null) {
                opt = [];
                opt.enableRangeSelection = true;
                opt.alwaysHalfDay = true;
                opt.language = "fr";
                opt.displayWeekNumber = true;
                opt.dataSource = []; // need to set this with 
                                     // the values from a service
            }
```

//////////////////////////

```
$(window).mouseup(function (e) {
    if (_this._mouseDown) {
        _this._mouseDown = false;
        _this._refreshRange();

        var minDate = _this._rangeStart < _this._rangeEnd ? _this._rangeStart : _this._rangeEnd;
        var maxDate = _this._rangeEnd > _this._rangeStart ? _this._rangeEnd : _this._rangeStart;
        console.log("minDate - " + minDate.toLocaleDateString());
        console.log("maxDate - " + maxDate.toLocaleDateString());

        //Need to call a post service here

        _this._triggerEvent('selectRange', { startDate: minDate, endDate: maxDate });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am inclined to put the event handler in a `.run` method:

```
̶$̶(̶w̶i̶n̶d̶o̶w̶)̶.̶m̶o̶u̶s̶e̶u̶p̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶e̶)̶ ̶{̶
app.run(function($window, myService) {
    angular.element($window).on("mousedown", function(e) {
        var _this /* ???? */
.       if (_this._mouseDown) {
            _this._mouseDown = false;
            _this._refreshRange();

            var minDate = _this._rangeStart < _this._rangeEnd ? _this._rangeStart : _this._rangeEnd;
            var maxDate = _this._rangeEnd > _this._rangeStart ? _this._rangeEnd : _this._rangeStart;
            console.log("minDate - " + minDate.toLocaleDateString());
            console.log("maxDate - " + maxDate.toLocaleDateString());

            //Call `myService` here

            _this._triggerEvent('selectRange', { startDate: minDate, endDate: maxDate });
        }
    });
});
```

But I have no idea where to get the value for the `_this` object.